# How to do a 'search a take best' function in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings!

I'm looking for a way to search a collection for the object that best satisfies my criteria. Since I have to do this quite often, I was looking into how to execute the query using LINQ, but cannot find a simple way to do this that doesn't 'appear' to waste time.

A functional implementation would be:

`collection.OrderByDescending(f => FitFunction(f)).First()`

But this seems to unnecessarily do the sorting. I really just need a linear scan. The Min LINQ function returns the best fit, rather than the object which produces the best fit, and so doesn't seem useful.

For clarity, the non-LINQ code I would traditionally write (and have done so so many times):

```
T best;
float bestFit = something very low;

foreach (T ob in collection)
{
  float fit = FitFunction(ob);
  if (fit > bestFit)
  {
    bestFit = fit;
    best = ob;
  }
}
return best;
```

And I think I may just make my own extension method to do that; but it seems to me that there must already be a way to do this already within LINQ.

Thanks!

Comment: instead of passing the `ob` object to the `FitFunction`, can't you have the result of the `FitFunction` as a property of `ob`, therefore enabling `collection.Min(t => t.FitValue)` ?

Comment: @vlad: Unfortunately, the Enumerable.Min() method returns the min value projection ... not the object instance `t`, which is what the OP is looking for. This is why MoreLINQ introduced the MinBy and MaxBy operators.

Comment: The difficulty is that the Min function would yield `t.FitValue`, rather than the `t`. Aside from that, this would necessarily tie the FitValue to the object, which I would avoid to keep the code loosely coupled.

Comment: (Btw, thanks bdukes for the formatting help)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is essentially a Top-N problem based on a predicate with the additional constraint that N always is equal to 1.** Unfortunately, there is no built-in LINQ operator that performs a TopN() operation ... but as you point out, it's not too hard to write one yourself.

The [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library has an implementation of the [MaxBy()](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) operator, which allows you to specify a predicate - and would also work.

Comment: The `System.Interactive` assembly that comes with the Reactive Extensions (Rx) has an implementation of `MaxBy` as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx